# Iterating objects and replacing values from columns

Tags: python, mongodb

I require assistance regarding iterating throught a database on mongodb but am unsure how to get single object values from mongodb by using .find , I am getting a "dict" object has no attribute likely because all the values retrieve isnt a single object.

```
for document in supermarketCollection.find(
    {},
    {
        "_id": 0,
        "Supermarket_Name": 0,
        "Chain_Name": 0,
        "Location": 0,
    },
):
    cookies = {
        "hideLocationOverlay": "true",
        "selectedShippingState": document.state,
        "selectedPostalCode": document.postal_code,
    }
```

Im tryinng to loop throught the database and input the values state and postal_code into cookies in every iteration loop.

but the output when I display it before it reaches the cookie

```
{'postal_code': '53300', 'state': 'Kuala Lumpur'}
{'postal_code': '54200', 'state': 'Kuala Lumpur'}
{'postal_code': '52100', 'state': 'Kuala Lumpur'}
{'postal_code': '55100', 'state': 'Kuala Lumpur'}
{'postal_code': '43300', 'state': 'Selangor'}
{'postal_code': '40100', 'state': 'Selangor'}
{'postal_code': '48000', 'state': 'Selangor'}
{'postal_code': '43200', 'state': 'Selangor'}
{'postal_code': '41200', 'state': 'Selangor'}
{'postal_code': '41150', 'state': 'Selangor'}
{'postal_code': '81100', 'state': 'Johor'}
{'postal_code': '81200', 'state': 'Johor'}
{'postal_code': '81000', 'state': 'Johor'}
{'postal_code': '81750', 'state': 'Johor'}
{'postal_code': '81300', 'state': 'Johor'}
{'postal_code': '81100', 'state': 'Johor'}
{'postal_code': '34000', 'state': 'Perak'}
{'postal_code': '32040', 'state': 'Perak'}
{'postal_code': '31200', 'state': 'Perak'}
{'postal_code': '31400', 'state': 'Perak'}
{'postal_code': '31650', 'state': 'Perak'}
{'postal_code': '93150', 'state': 'Sarawak'}
{'postal_code': '15050', 'state': 'Kelantan'}
{'postal_code': '71800', 'state': 'Negeri Sembilan'}
{'postal_code': '70300', 'state': 'Negeri Sembilan'}
{'postal_code': '14000', 'state': 'Pulau Pinang'}
{'postal_code': '75450', 'state': 'Melaka'}
{'postal_code': '75400', 'state': 'Melaka'}
```

What im expecting is the output is :

```
cookies = {
        "hideLocationOverlay": "true",
        "selectedShippingState": "Kuala Lumpur",
        "selectedPostalCode": "53300",
    }
```